# Forgotten Swipe Pattern lock for Nexus 6P (but fingerprint works!)

Tags: password, pattern-lock, nexus

I have a Google Nexus 6P with Copperhead OS installed on it. I forgot the pattern to unlock the screen. Is there any way I can recover (a part) of the data on my phone? I am pretty sure that the answer is going to be "no way", but I just want to ask to make sure, before I wipe the phone.

I DO have a fingerprint in the phone, which works. Unfortunately - for some security reason - it wants the pattern as well.

Maybe I can add, that I *kind of* remember the swipe pattern. I am sure about a middle part, but not about the beginning and the end. Unfortutely I have tried so many combinations by now (even keeping a book), that I have to wait 240 seconds now until I am allowed to enter the next try. (First I had to wait 20, then 30, 60, 120 seconds, now 240.) I had about 55 tries by now.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do since you have such an open phone is unlock the bootloader temporarily and flash a custom recovery to remove the password related files. Here's how:

1. Unlock your bootloader - [1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/general/guides-how-to-guides-beginners-t3206928/amp/)
2. Install a custom recovery - [1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/general/guides-how-to-guides-beginners-t3206928/amp/)
3. Use the custom recovery's "File Manager" feature to remove the following files - [2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/general/guides-how-to-guides-beginners-t3206928/amp/):

```
/data/system/password.key
/data/system/pattern.key
/data/system/locksettings.db
/data/system/locksettings.db-shm
/data/system/locksettings.db-wal
```

4. Reboot your device
5. It should now have no password/pattern, enjoy your device
6. Reinstall stock recovery (should be automatically reinstalled when you reboot) and relocking bootloader - [3](https://amp.reddit.com/r/Nexus6P/comments/6y86zc/easiest_way_to_relock_bootloader/) (Optional)

Comment: *"This will erase all user data from the device!"* have you read the instructions you shared?

Comment: He have _Copperhead OS_, he have his bootloader unlocked.

Comment: main purpose of *CopperheadOS* is **Security** therefore the last step in official install instructions is [locking bootloader](https://copperhead.co/android/docs/install/#locking-the-bootloader)

Comment: even on unlocked bootloader this method would cause data loss (for FBE file-based encryption in general) but in this case even for FDE full disk encryption, because *CopperheadOS* generates separate disk encryption keys for each user profile based on login credentials which get unrecoverable on deleted *locksettings.db* (besides this TWRP might not work on fingerprint but asking for pattern instead)